# Compare Variable with Model Attributes

Tags: c#, regex, attributes

I have a class:

```
public class Email
{
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must enter valid email.")]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a DB that contains "bad" data where `Address` is no longer supported by my new RegEx.

my code is as follows:

```
Email newUser = new Email();
foreach (string email in user.Emails)
{
   // Something here to check the value 'email' fits the RegEx
   newUser.Address = email;
}
```

is there a way to make sure the value i want to assign matches the regex?

Comment: [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx)

Comment: Do you need to also implement length restriction? Like maximum of 256 characters?

Comment: I don't think any emails addresses will go near the limit but let's say yes... how would that code look?

Comment: I posted an answer with a regex-only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Email newUser = new Email();
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$");   
foreach (string email in user.Emails)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(email) ) {
       newUser.Address = email;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to avoid duplication of regex pattern and also validate other attributes, you may use this method to perform validation:

```
public bool CheckValidation(Type type, string property, object value) {
  PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  if (propertyInfo == null) {
     throw new ArgumentException("property");
  }
  var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes();
  foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
     if (attribute is ValidationAttribute) {
        var validationAttribute = (ValidationAttribute)attribute;
        try {
           validationAttribute.Validate(value, string.Empty);
        }
        catch (ValidationException) {
           return false;
        }
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

and then use it in this way:

```
foreach (string email in user.Emails)
{
    if (CheckValidation(typeof(Email), "Address", email) {
       newUser.Address = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement 2 conditions: the email regex check and the length check.

You can combine that into 1 regex (I also shortened it a bit with `(?i)` case insensitive option):

```
Email newUser = new Email();
Regex rxMail = new Regex(@"(?i)^(?=.{0,256}$)[a-z0-9_\+-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$");
foreach (string email in user.Emails)
{
   if (rxMail.IsMatch(email))
   {
       newUser.Address = email;
   }
}
```

The length is checked with a positive look-ahead `(?=.{0,256}$)` at the beginning of the pattern.